# Cannot pass third argument to bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I think the answer will be pretty simple for you, however I cannot handle it alone. First of all function in the script looks like:

```
function assertEqual() {

    local expected=$1
    local actual=$2
    local message=$3

    echo $message

    if [ "$actual" = "$expected" ]
    then
        echo "Test OK (actual value: $actual)"
        return 0
    else
        echo "Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: $expected, ACTUAL VALUE: $actual, WILL ABORT"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

The logic of the function do what it has to do, it is correct however I cannot find a way to print $message into console:

```
local message=$3
echo $message
```

I am invoking function like this:

```
assertEqual "$MOV_ID_REVS_RECS" $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId) "Comparing id's"   
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations  | length") "Comparing recommendations length"    
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length") "Comparing reviews length"
```

Output I get is like:

```
Test OK (HTTP Code: 200)
Test OK (HTTP Code: 200)
Test OK (HTTP Code: 200)
Wait for messages to be processed... 
Test OK (HTTP Code: 200)

Test OK (actual value: 2)

Test OK (actual value: 3)

Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: 3, ACTUAL VALUE: 1, WILL ABORT
```

You can see that there are blank white rows which means that I am passing third argument wrongly right?

Comment: This will fail when there are multiple words in `$2` (or `$1`, for that matter). Make sure to doublequote your vars, unless you really want the other behaviour: `expected="$1"`, `echo "$message"`...  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is pretty smart about these things.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. At minimum include `$RESPONSE`, or better yet factor it out. That said, Amadan is probably right - it's probably word splitting that's causing the problem.

Comment: Since you are using bash, you can pass an array as a hack and store your function arguments in a local copy. E.g. `function assertEqual() { local arr=("$@") ...` and then call your function by passing the values stored in an array, e.g. `assertEqual "${argarray[@]}"` (the quotes are **required**) This will preserve the elements and avoid word-splitting that occurs in your attempt. Just fill your `argarray` before calling the function.

Comment: what is output of `$(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId) `

Comment: @Amadan This works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be multiple words in the substitution while passing the argument.

```
assertEqual "$MOV_ID_REVS_RECS" $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId) "Comparing id's"   
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations  | length") "Comparing recommendations length"    
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length") "Comparing reviews length"
```

Please try to quote the `$(echo $RE...)` > `"$(echo $RE...)"` in the arguments and test the results.
Alternatively, try passing just `assertEqual 3 test "Comparing reviews length"` if all arguments work properly.